# Nucleo f446re can't debug/load code, may be bricked(?)

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32f4, stm32cubeide, nucleo

I have a problem with my nucleo f446re board. Until yesterday it worked normally; I was trying to communicate wit a hcsr04 sensor (ultrasound proximity sensor) with i2c since it was supported and I definitely messed up the pin config (I believe so because that's the only logical explaination). After compiling, when I hit debug this error showed up:

"
target no device found error in initializing st-link device. reason: no device found on target.
"

After this the board seems to be completely bricked. I have tried uinstalling and reinstalling drivers for the USB connection with windows, I have downloaded and tried using stm32programmer and the old one st-link utility, trying connecting and erasing flash (even pulling down NRST or pulling up/down BOOT0) but I got only errors. The board is detected but I can't connect to it. Anyone has got any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You might have fried the board if you messed up the pin config. I've done that before; it only killed the GPIO pins I messed up. But I could imagine it might break the entire chip. You should try another boards if you can get one, they're pretty cheap. And get the pin config right next time.

Comment: You have not indicated whether you have tried disabling read out protection.  For that to be the problem, you would have to set it of course, but that is possible.  "_I messed up the pin configuration_" is not useful information; you need to describe exactly what you did, preferably with the code that was "messed up", and what was connected to the pin at the time.

Comment: ... Either way, as it stands this is probably an off topic question on SO if you truly broke the hardware. The important part of your STM32Programmer screenshot is _plain text_.  You should post that in preference to a screenshot.  In any event use SO's image hosting rather then linking to an independent imgur page - SO uses imgur in any case, but the way you did it prevents the images being in-lined which an editor with sufficient rep can do for you.  Fixed it for you.

Comment: No, i have not disabled read out protection. I said that I have messed up the pin config because is literally the only thing I have done, other than starting the I2C communication in the main. I have selected I2C1 pins and set the correct parameters from the ide

Comment: By the way, thank you for editing the post, I have little experience with stack overflow

Comment: Apart from doing a bulk erase, trying to disable RDP will do no harm - worth a try.  You cannot really break the processor by misconfiguring the GPIO, what you can do is set it up such that an externally applied voltage could break it.  Which is why I asked about both the code and the hardware.  But in the end "is my hardware bricked?" is not really a question for SO which is about _software_.  Now if you were to present the code tht you believe broke it, that may be worthy of consideration here.  Otherwise it is OT hetre and you might try https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Also to check - are both CN2 jumbers on the board in the ON state?  If not the on-board JTAG/SWD hardware debugger is disconnected.  Which would correlate with the information CubeProgrammer is reporting where it knows what board is connected but cannot find a target processor.  See Table 4 and Figure 3 of https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um1724-stm32-nucleo64-boards-mb1136-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: Yep, both cn2 jumpers are on. I'll provide the cubeIDE project. 
here it is https://mega.nz/file/q91xASwD#ykgW00_9l32OOrGNeoXTRTrZ5DJLMH6DTgudRrmSec0

Comment: i've tried to disable rdp using st link utility, but it didn't work since it could not connect